# ¿Cómo reemplazo o represento un & de SCSS en CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scss

Hola tengo un detalle al utilizar un código con Js y Jquery en mi archivo HTML.

En HTML: Tengo un div con el id="target" `<div #="target"></div>` (Tengo mis archivos Jquery y Js ya enlazados de manera correcta)

En CSS: Simplemente le doy estilos para formar un cuadrado con un fondo negro. (width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #000; etc..

Y el problema aquí:

En JS con Jquery:

```
var $target = $('#target');

$target.on('click mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('yellow');
})
```

Lo que busco lograr es que cambie de color al entrar o salir el Mouse, pero no logro conseguirlo, así que creo que el problema es por tratarse de las JERARQUÍAS (ID vs CLASS) ya que intento agregarle a ese div cuadrado con un id, una clase que hace que cambie de color pero no logro conseguirlo. Alguien podría apoyarme?

PD: Veo que en SCSS se resuelve fácil con agregar un &.clase { los estilos} pero no se como lograr eso en CSS. por eso el título :)

Comment: Gracias por la correción! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es un efecto hover, se puede hacer solo con css y no necesitarías usar JS, quedaría así:

```css
#target{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: black;
}

#target:hover{
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div id="target">
  
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y el mismo código pero en SCSS sería:

```css
#target{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: black;

 &:hover{
  background: yellow;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias! Realmente se trata de que estoy estudiando algo de Jquery entonces si es necesario usarlo jaja. pero Ya pude resolverlo, simplemente encontré que la forma de hacer esto era especificando bien en css algo como esto : #(El ID).(la clase que interactua) {

Comment: a ok, bueno igual genial que hayas podido resolver esto tú solo, saludos